# window installer prerequisites missing in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, setup-deployment

i have been trying to make a setup for my WPF project which uses SQL server. on publishing process, at the point of selecting prerequisites in the prerequisites dialogue box I'm missing window installer . How can i fix that please [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPeXI.png).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project to get the project type you are looking for.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Another Installer project you can use is WIX

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension

Comment: I have installed the extensions but none seem to work. After installing I restarted my machine but no effect took place